# Nuget package update - Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget

when restoring a locally created nuget package I receive the following error:

```
Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64'.
Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component
```

[image: Error screenshot]

When I look at the nuget build I see the following

[[image: Nuget output screenshot]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik7mm.png)

The highlighted yellow "missing" dlls in the screenshot above do actually exist in the project.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 professional

Thanks for any help
Mark

Comment: Is  `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64` your own nuget package or just a microsoft nuget package? In `nuget.org`, I cannot find `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64` package and seems it does not exists under it. Was it a dependency of your nuget package?

Comment: try removing the sql client nuget and re-adding it

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments; I have tried removing and re-adding the sql client package.

Also, the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64 nuget package is a dependency on System.Data.SqlClient (https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni/)

Comment: I cannot see `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64` as a dependency of [System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni/). Is it your own package?

Comment: Sorry! My bad - it's a dependency of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Or you could create a new empty project to install these packages to check whether the issue persists.

Comment: Hi, I have tried regsvr32 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll and I am unable to do so as it says that it is not a valid COM object (No entry point). I have cleaned the cache and re-installed the package as well. I get the same problem across multiple versions of Visual Studio (2015, 2017 and 2019)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nuget package update - Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64

Please try the following steps:

**1)** close VS Instance, delete `nuget.config` file under  `C:\Users\xxx(current use account)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`.

**2)** delete `.vs` hidden folder under your solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder then restart your project to test again.

**3)** Please try to create a new empty project in VS2019 and test whether you can install the package `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

**If** you cannot install it, you should note that whether your VS or OS has broken. If the new project has no error, the issue is your project itself. You can try the above steps to troubleshoot the issue.

**If** the issue still persists in the new project,

You can try to [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update VS to the latest version.

**Also**, try to update OS or [use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system).

**Besides**, try another PC to test whether the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you're trying to delete Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.**SNI.x64**

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient & Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.**SNI.x64** are interdependent ,
you cannot delete **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64** alone without deleting  **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** first

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.X64 or X32 files need to be removed from release folder before creating package.

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.X64 will be added automatically while adding Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

So, remove the dll before creating the package and then try installing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had other Nuget packages that used `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` (which automatically included `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI`). When I down-graded my other Nuget packages, even while keeping `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`/`SNI` versions the same, then this error went away.